# passing response ajax to handlebars

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, handlebars.js

I have some problem with handlebars,

I already import handlebars library and jquery, everything seems work fine.
The problem is when i have an response ajax and passing it to handlebars, then  i try to open the web it shows nothing.

**javascript**

```
<script>
    var userTable = $('#user-table'); // Ambil tempat template akan dimasukan
    var itemUserTableRaw = $('#user-item-table').html(); // Ambil template
    var itemUserTableTemplate = Handlebars.compile(itemUserTableRaw); // Compile template menjadi handlebars template

    $(function () {
        var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
        var header = "X-CSRF-TOKEN";
        $(document).ajaxSend(function (e, xhr, options) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
        });
    });

    $.ajax({
        method: 'get',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "http://localhost:9090/users",
    }).then(function (response) {
        userTable.html(itemUserTableTemplate(response));
    });

</script>
```

**handlebars template**

```
<script id="user-table" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each data}}
    <tr>          
    <td>{{username}}</td>
    <td>{{password}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

**view.blade.php**

```
<table id="tabel" class="table table-bordered table-hover"> 
    <thead>
        <th class="col-head" >
            Username
        </th>
        <th class="col-head" >
            Password
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id=user-item-table>
    </tbody>
</table>
@include('/handlebars/user')
<script src="{{ asset('node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('node_modules/handlebars/dist/handlebars.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('Assets/user.js')}}"></script>
```

Thanks for your help